# DJI SDK throws the error "Application is not registered" Code=-1001 after calling the method DJIMissionManager.prepare

Tags: ios, swift, dji-sdk

After adding five `DJIWaypoints` to the `djiWaypointMission` I call the following method.

```
djiMissionManager.prepare(djiWaypointMission,
                              withProgress: {(progress: Float) -> Void in } ,
                              withCompletion: {(error: Error?) -> Void in })
```

At runtime the method throws

```
Error Domain=DJISDKErrorDomain Code=-1001 "Application is not registered.(code:-1001)" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Application is not registered.(code:-1001)}
```

In the code first I check in the callback method `sdkManagerDidRegisterAppWithError` whether the application registered successfully and then call the `prepareMission`. So it is impossible that the application is not registered. Particularly because the video streaming works fine.

I appreciate any hints on how I can solve this problem or get a more detailed error message.

Answer (score 1):

The problem was that I initialized the `DJIMissionManager` object directly inside my `ViewController` using the `DJIMissionManager.init()` constructor.

**Solution:** I moved the object initialization into the `viewDidLoad()` and used `DJIMissionManager.sharedInstance()` to get an instance of the `DJIMissionManager` object.